# How to remove "updated_at" while keeping the "created_at" in Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, timestamp

In Laravel I have a model that is created only but not updated. So, I want to remove only the `updated_at` field. But the `created_at` field is required.

So how can I remove only the `updated_at` field while keeping the `created_at` field?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your model add these two lines:

```
public $timestamps = ["created_at"]; //only want to used created_at column
const UPDATED_AT = null; //and updated by default null set
```

**second way:**

```
public $timestamps = false; //by default timestamp true
```

add function like this:

```
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value) { 
    $this->attributes['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); 
}
```

from laravel 10 you can use `withoutTimestamps()` method

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->withoutTimestamps(function () use ($user) {
    $user->update(['name' => 'John Doe']);
});
```

for more info about laravel timestamp  [see](https://laraveldaily.com/8-tricks-with-laravel-timestamps/)

Comment: I liked your first solution

Comment: @Blip i also used first solution

Comment: copied to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718967/14290461

Answer (score 3):

The answer you checked as the solution is not what the question asked for.

you can drop the `updated_at` column just in the table creation migration:

```
Schema::create('sample', function (Blueprint $table)    
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->dropColumn('updated_at');
});
```

Comment: The answer you posted is not an answer to my question at all. I didn't ask about migration. The question is about eloquent ORM. Now coming to what you have answered, I would like to add here that you have first added the **updated_at** and then removed the column. Would it not be better if you didn't add it in the first place?

Comment: @Blip Yeap, you're right, i tought your question is for migrations. the thing is you can't just use `updated_at` on migrations, it comes with `created_at` in the `timestamps()`. jignesh Joisar's answer is the correct solution for ORMs.
my google search for migrations led me to this post, so i let this answer stay here maybe it helps someone.

Comment: I agree with you. But my suggestion is that you should replace the lines `$table->dropColumn('update_at')` and `$table->timestamps()` with a single line `$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();` as it would be more appropriate to just add one column instead of adding two columns and removing one column.

Comment: @Blip Yup, that’s exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you look inside the trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps` you will find many options.

**My favourite** is setting a constant on your model like this.

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

But you also can overwrite a function that sets an updated_at field like that

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value): self
{
    // Do nothing.
    return $this;
}
```

or, you can overwrite another function like this

```
public function getUpdatedAtColumn()
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add the line below to your model. This applies to insert and select queries.

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

If you don't need to create a column as well, remove the below the line in the  database/migration file.

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Comment: I want the `created_at` but don't require the `updated_at`, You have not provided the solution to that. Your solution results in removal of both `created_at` and `updated_at`.