# Eloquent Belongs-to-Many relation using custom intermediate Table Models without 'updated_at' field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and in my application, I have Belongs to Many relations with a custom model, and I want to remove the 'updated_at' field.

**Relation**

```
public function tracks() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Track::class)
        ->using(CollectionTrack::class)
        ->withPivot('sort'  , 'created_at' , 'id');
}
```

**Custom model**

```
class CollectionTrack extends Pivot
{
    use Sortable;

    public const UPDATED_AT = null;
    public $incrementing = true;
    
    public static function enableAutoSort () {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I want to sync, it tries to fill the `updated_at` field.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

However, I removed the updated_at from the Model using the following line.

```
public const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

And also, only get the created_at in `withPivot`.

When I remove the `created_at` from withPivot, the issue goes away, but in that case, when I retrieve the data `created_at` won't be in the fields.

**Note**: my goal is to disable the `updated_at` timestamp and only have `created_at` so when I attach a new record, the created_at set and when I retrieve it, the model has these pivot fields `'sort', 'created_at', 'id.'`

Comment: Just try to change the updated_at field to nullable bro

Comment: Did you have tried this answer? It should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886497/how-to-only-use-created-at-in-laravel/36043796

Answer (score 3):

I think you can remove `$table->timestamps()` from your migration and just add a field `created_at` having default value current time stamp.

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

should work I guess.

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171175/5321614) you can refer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but there is no issue on the database side. the issue is retrieving the created_at field when I'm using a custom model for the intermediate table. It's like `withPivot` and custom model is not compatible with each other!

Comment: @Hamidreza can you try with `syncWithoutDetaching('updated_at')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships  ? will that avoid touching to updated_at field and your job will be done?  try that or we need to write some custom function I guess.

Comment: @Hamidreza did you tried this? also can you post your sync function call? have you tried combination of atatch and detach instead?

Answer (score 0):

You either have to declare `public $timestamps = false;` in every model, or create a `BaseModel`, define it there, and have all your models extend it instead of eloquent. Just bare in mind pivot tables MUST have timestamps if you're using Eloquent.

**Update:** Note that timestamps are no longer REQUIRED in pivot tables after Laravel v3.

**Update:** You can also disable timestamps by removing `$table->timestamps()` from your migration

Comment: i want to have created_at timestamp only and just disable the updated_at

Answer (score 0):

[ORIGINAL ANSWER: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171175/14290461](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171175/14290461)

In your model add these two lines:

```
public $timestamps = ["created_at"]; //only want to used created_at column
const UPDATED_AT = null; //and updated by default null set
```

second way:

```
public $timestamps = false; //by default timestamp false
```

add function like this:

```
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value) { 
    $this->attributes['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); 
}
```

for more info about laravel timestamp [see](https://laraveldaily.com/8-tricks-with-laravel-timestamps/)